# How do i authenticate google sign in using firebase

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Please can anyone tell why my sign in to google page is just popping up and disappearing almost immediately on chrome

I used firebase authentification for the sgin in. thisis the code

```
const OAuth = () => {
  const onGoogleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const auth = getAuth();
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
      const user = result.user;

      // Moved console.log(user) here
      console.log(user);

      const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);

      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

      if (!docSnap.exists) {
        await setDoc(docRef, {
          name: user.displayName,
          email: user.email,
          timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Could not sign in with Google");
    }
  };
```